# Update table with values from another table

Tags: guptateamdeveloper

I have 2 tables, one With a unique key the other With no unique key. In both tables there are one column "name" which are identical.  I want to update table two With the unique key from table one where table.one.name = table.two.name.  There are multi rows in table two, only one in table one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle database is it possible with sql command:

```
update table2 a set a.col = :nValue 
where a.name = (select b.name from table1 b where b.name = a.name and b.key = :nUniqueKey)
```

In others databases it will be the similar.